# Splitting method if iteration matrix has no eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

We are interested in solving a linear system $Ax=b$ in numerical analysis. We choose a preconditioner matrix $P$ and we studied in my course "splitting method". We defined the iteration matrix $B:=I-P^{-1}A$. A theorem says that a splitting method with iteration matrix $B$ is convergent for any initial guess $x_0$ if and only if the spectral radius of $B$ denoted by $\rho(B)$  is strictly smaller than $1$.

However, since we are dealing with real matrices only, what happens to the result if $B$ has no real eigenvalues ?

Comment: You mean ".. has no *real* eigenvalues?"

Comment: Yes like the matrix (0 -1; 1 0) for example

Comment: @Kilkik The "spectral radius" in this context is the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues, including complex eigenvalues. So, the spectral radius of $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$ is $1$ because its eigenvalues $\pm i$ have absolute value $1$.